# enabling LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE in mysql-libmysqlclient for node?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I need to use LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE using  mysql-libmysqlclient in node. However I get an error

[Error: Query error #1148: The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version]

This does not happen running the same command from sequel pro so the issue is most likely with the connection used by mysql-libmysqlclient.

Anoyone know what parameters to send to mysql-libmysqlclient in order to fix this?

initializing connection:

```
secrets = stuff
mysql_db = mysql.createConnectionQueuedSync()

mysql_db.initSync()
mysql_db.realConnectSync secrets.host, secrets.user, secrets.password, secrets.database
mysql_db.connectError

module.exports = exports = mysql_db
```

Sending query:

```
mysql_db = require('./config/mysql_db')
sql_insert_into = "LOAD DATA local INFILE 'file_to_send.txt'     
into table #{table.name}    
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'    
LINES TERMINATED by '\\n'
"

mysql_db.query sql_insert_into, (err, answer)->
  console.log "sent " + sql_insert_into
```

The error I get:

```
[Error: Query error #1148: The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version]
```

Minor note: I program in coffee script but this shouldn't change anything

Comment: Can you share the relevant code fragment with us please?

Answer (score 0):

If LOAD DATA LOCAL is disabled, either in the server or the client, a client that attempts to issue such a statement receives the following error message:

```
ERROR 1148: The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version
```

You can refer MySql website link below for how to enable:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data-local.html

Comment: Do you know how to enable it for mysql-libmysqlclient?

I have no issue running the same command manually.